# Sorting string array on the basis of a match string

Tags: javascript, string, json, search

I have a JSON object containing a number of strings. I also have a match string . Now I wish to arrange the object of strings on the basis of how closely (more) they match with match string.

How this can be done using Javascript.

Suppose, I searched for `Philips SHM6110U Headphone`

Search will then fetch following result.

```
[
    {
        "position": 12,
        "link": "http:\/\/www.talash.com\/buy-online-philips-shl5001-hi-fi-headphone-headband-headphone-india-product.html",
        "image": "http:\/\/staticus.talash.com\/product_images\/p\/092\/DM1573_1lg__52708_thumb.jpg",
        "prod": "Philips Shl5001 Hi Fi Headphone Headband Headphone",
        "price": "Rs. 1000"
    },
    {
        "position": 12,
        "link": "http:\/\/www.talash.com\/buy-online-philips-shl5000-hi-fi-headphone-headband-headphone-india-product.html",
        "image": "http:\/\/staticus.talash.com\/product_images\/n\/497\/DM1572_1lg__57945_thumb.jpg",
        "prod": "Philips Shl5000 Hi Fi Headphone Headband Headphone",
        "price": "Rs. 1030"
    }
]​
```

Now, I have to sort them according to the match string "Philips SHM6110U Headphone" and the `prod` value of JSON.

Suggesting an algorithm or sample source code will do!

Comment: Please include an example of exactly what the source data structure looks like (array of strings?  object of keys/strings?).  And, you will have to supply info on "how closely they match" is determined.

Comment: Is it relevant that you get the data as JSON? Do you have problems parsing it? Or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: What do you mean "JSON object"? Do you mean "array"? (If not, how does the concept of "arrange" work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it finally using a number of criteria :-

1. Individual word matching of the search result and search query
2. Extra credits for complete matching of result and search query
3. Portion of length of all words matching to the total length of search result
4. Extra credits if the search query appears at an index less than half of the total length of search result
5. A price filter for further improvements in result.

Here is the final [result](http://compare.buyhatke.com/comp.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a comparison function to [Array.prototype.sort](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11).

```
var results = [
  {"position": 12,
    ...
   "prod": "Philips Shl5001 Hi Fi Headphone Headband Headphone",
    ...
  },
  {"position": 12,
    ...
   "prod": "Philips Shl5000 Hi Fi Headphone Headband Headphone",
    ...
  }
]​;

results.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.prod < b.prod? -1 : a.prod == b.prod? 0 : 1;
});
```

The result will be the array sorted by *obj.prod* values.

Comment: But, I don't wish to sort the array alphabetically. I just wish to give them a weightage according to how close or apart they are as per the search string

Comment: Put whatever logic you like in the compare function to determine the value to return. An equality comparison was a simple example, you can use something more sophisticated if you want.